# How to transform with php likes and dislikes in a 5star rating system?

Tags: php, rating-system, rich-snippets

Let's say i have a database entry like this:

```
video_id | likes | dislikes

 654         5          12
```

What i want to do is to transform the number of likes and dislikes into a 5 stars rating for [google rich snippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146645#Aggregate_reviews).

Do you have any ideas? Some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a rating between 1 and 5, you could do the following:

```
$rating = 1 + 4 * $likes / ($likes + $dislikes);
```

Remember to take special care of the case where there are no votes, though.

Comment: thank you, i tried the code and it works. But i have a question, if the page has 10 likes and 100 dislikes the pege gets a rating of 1.36363636364. Shouldn't be the rating like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ?  I asked because i didn't see on google numbers like that.

Comment: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=172705 hmm... i've foud `Rating: <span class="rating">4.5</span>` is there a option to get a number like x or x.x ?

Comment: i used `round($rating, 1);` Thank you again.